# loop to remove some strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to remove some character in my string but I have an error, I have tride different ways loop but it is still not working

My question is how can I loop over a string and remove characters ?

here is my code :

```
MyList= [",", ":", "\"", "=", "&", ";", "%", "$","@", "%", "^",
         "*", "(", ")", "{", "}","[", "]", "|", "/", "\\", ">",
         "<", "-",'!', '?', '.', "'",'--', '---', "#"]

for remove in MyList:   

        mystring =re.sub(remove, "", "I am trying this code")
        print (remove)
```

And I have this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-386-df22385a9f06> in <module>()
      5 for remove in MyList:
      6 
----> 7         mystring =re.sub(remove, "", "I am trying this code ! ? /")
      8         print (remove)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    189     a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
    190     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 191     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    192 
    193 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\re.py in _compile(pattern, flags)
    299     if not sre_compile.isstring(pattern):
    300         raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
--> 301     p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
    302     if not (flags & DEBUG):
    303         if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\sre_compile.py in compile(p, flags)
    560     if isstring(p):
    561         pattern = p
--> 562         p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
    563     else:
    564         pattern = None

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py in parse(str, flags, pattern)
    853 
    854     try:
--> 855         p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
    856     except Verbose:
    857         # the VERBOSE flag was switched on inside the pattern.  to be

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py in _parse_sub(source, state, verbose, nested)
    414     while True:
    415         itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
--> 416                            not nested and not items))
    417         if not sourcematch("|"):
    418             break

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py in _parse(source, state, verbose, nested, first)
    614             if not item or (_len(item) == 1 and item[0][0] is AT):
    615                 raise source.error("nothing to repeat",
--> 616                                    source.tell() - here + len(this))
    617             if item[0][0] in _REPEATCODES:
    618                 raise source.error("multiple repeat",

error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

Sorry for My novice question

Comment: Looks like you have an invalid regular expression.  This tool is very helpful for making sure you have valid regular expressions:
https://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: why aren't you just using `str.replace` ?

Comment: Looks like a XY problem. is your goal to remove _all_ punctuation from your text?

Comment: it's strange to remove single dash, then double dash, then triple dash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions for that. Just use `str.replace`:

```
>>> MyList= [",", ":", "\"", "=", "&", ";", "%", "$","@", "%", "^",
...          "*", "(", ")", "{", "}","[", "]", "|", "/", "\\", ">",
...          "<", "-",'!', '?', '.', "'",'--', '---', "#"]
>>> mystring = "Helo, world!?"
>>> for s in MyList:
...     mystring = mystring.replace(s, '')
...
>>> mystring
'Helo world'
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of workarounds already posted, but no one has explained the error yet. The docs for re.sub() say:

`re.sub(pattern, repl, string, ...) - Return the string obtained by replacing ... pattern in string by the replacement repl`

So after iterating through a few of the symbols in my list, we got to this:

```
re.sub("*", "", "I am trying this code")
```

So you are trying to replace `*` with `""` - but `*` is a "special" character used in regular expressions, and in this case, `"*"` is an illegal / invalid regular expression. `*` is a quantifier in regex, and means "return as many repetitions of the previous regex as possible" - but there isn't a previous regex in that string.

`"*"` is usually used with `"."` as in `".*"` which means match any single character (`"."`) as many times as possible (`"*"`).

Update: here's how I'd remove symbols from strings:

```
import string

s = "I# am trying th<>is code!"
print(s.translate(None, string.punctuation))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to remove all punctuation from your string, a single regular expression keeping all the other characters (`_` and space included) would be:

```
import re

s = "Hello, world! how are you?"

print(re.sub("[^ \w]","",s))
```

result:

```
Hello world how are you
```

it's really more efficient than x replace calls in a loop (creates as many strings) or a regular expression with `|`.

Answer (score 0):

Here an answer with a list comprehension and join, not the most elegant, nor fastest:

```
my_list= [",", ":", "\"", "=", "&", ";", "%", "$","@", "%", "^",
         "*", "(", ")", "{", "}","[", "]", "|", "/", "\\", ">",
         "<", "-",'!', '?', '.', "'",'--', '---', "#"]

my_string = "Hello, world!?"

# one liner
my_string = ''.join([c for c in my_string if c not in my_list])


print(my_string)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also combine the list into a single re expression:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\b(" + "|".join(MyList) + ")\\W")
pattern.sub("", mystring )
```

Comment: this won't work, a lot of those symbols need escaping.